# method required() error when building java maven module

Tags: java, maven

When I am building my maven module, I am getting the following error. There was no error in my module if don't build.

```
Symbol  : method required()
[ERROR] location: @interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef
```

I have already added the below dependency in my pom.xml also.

```
               <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Sometimes your .m2/repository gets messed up and all you can do is clear it out so you have a fresh cache.

Comment: Are you sure your compiler source and target levels are set to 1.5 or higher?  And you are using a 1.5 or higher JDK?

Comment: ya I am using JDK 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem when compiling a project with a WSDL in netbeans 7.3.1 or higher and found some help online that may help you also.

For us though it compiled in netbeans 6.9.1 but not in 7.3.1. Also moving the project to use JDK 1.7 resolves it also but our code needs to run on servers with 1.6... so our solution was:

find the file in netbeans-6.9.1/ide/modules/ext/jaxb/api/jaxb-api.jar and copy that to you /usr/lib/jvm/[java version]/jre/lib/endorsed/. directory.
Also copy netbeans-6.9.1/java/modules/ext/jaxws22/api/jaxws-api.jar to the /endorsed directory.

We did not have the endorsed dir so we just made it.

This allowed both netbeans and java to compile the project. Hope this helps you and anyone else with this issue. (May need to restart netbeans!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with wrong generated code for JDK 1.6

If you generate your code from the wsdl with wsimport command, you need set -target = 2.0 , for example

```
 wsimport -target 2.0  -keep sample.wsdl
```

-target
Generate code as per the given JAX-WS specification version. version 2.0 will generate compliant code for JAX-WS 2.0 spec.